# could not send data to com port

Tags: c++, serial-port

i want to send command in com port using c++ but this does not work

```
HANDLE hComm = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\COM1", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
unsigned char data[5]{0x02, 0x44, 0x43, 0x03, 0x06};
unsigned char data2[1]{0x05};
DWORD dwWritten;
dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;
dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;
SetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams);
WriteFile(hComm, &data, (int) sizeof(data), &dwWritten, NULL);
WriteFile(hComm, &data2, (int) sizeof(data2), &dwWritten, NULL);
DWORD bytesRead[10];
ReadFile(hComm, &input, 5, bytesRead, NULL);

CloseHandle(hComm);
```

Comment: What are the other 30-odd fields in `dcbSerialParams` set to?  You might want to use `GetCommState` to initialize the structure.

Answer (score -1):

Qt includes a module to deal with the serial port which is a good deal easier to work with than the Win32 API. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-index.html for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i need to send hex data like 0x44 0x02 0x43. And QSerialport support only const char*. Do you know ho to slove that?

Comment: I tried to do that, but my programm doesn't send anything to com port